# Are questions that ask *not* to offer readability/style/structure advice, on topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, asking-questions

The question in question: [A platform-independent implementation of "which" in Ruby](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/61434/a-platform-independent-implementation-of-which-in-ruby)

The OP has rather specifically asked that people *not* talk about how to improve the readability of the code (which, to my eyes, is nearly opaque).  He's convinced that his code has "*correct logic structure*", and "refusing to compromise it for the sake of readability is an option".

It's certainly an option when you're not posting questions about it.  But offering such suggestions is basically *what Code Review does*.

If someone is preemptively and emphatically declaring that advice off limits...is the question still on topic?

Comment: Also related: [Code Review vs. help me solve my problem](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/code-review-vs-help-me-solve-my-problem)